# "All Entries In Group" Database Design Aproach

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, relationship, database-schema

*Due to the Nature of the Question , searching for similar questions or articles  is quite difficult because keywords have a wide range of meaning. So if there is a similar question, pardon me.*

**The Problem**.
(Simplified)

I have a table of users.*(**Table User**)*

Each user Has his own assets ***(Table Asset Foreign key to user Id)***

2 Users can be cooperators. Each user selects the assets  he wants to share with the other. For use in this cooperation a Shared Group Is created containing the assets of user1 and user2  .***(Table Group FK CooperationId) (Join Table Asset In group)(Table UserCooperation)***

And now the tricky part.

In some occasions the user might want to Share **All** of his assets with a user.In order to avoid adding every time a new asset to the group manually we need a solution.

**Possible  Approaches.** (ordered by personal preference, with queering performance in mind).

1. Having an Extra **Table (All assets of user in group)**. So the
   query will first check if the user added all his assets in the group
   and skip querying by each asset id, but instead by userId.
2. Having **2 bool Flags on the Cooperation or Group Table** indicating if one user is sharing all his assets with the other and not a group. The query will first read this and if true it will skip the group logic and will just query by user id.
3. Keep also **2 bool Flags on the sharing Table** but to indicate that upon creation any asset has to be included in the Asset in Group table. So the business logic will handle inserting each new asset on that group. Query logic will not change on this occasion

**Alternate Structure.**

Instead of having a shared group for the cooperation, each user will have his own group and join the cooperation with his group. (Although a group has no meaning without a cooperation and the All In Group problem remains the same.)

Answer (score 2):

One scheme you might consider is to define an Asset Class which could be a direct Asset or Asset Group. An Asset Group would have access to one or more Assets. So a user can share with another user just an asset or an asset class which would consist of some or all of their assets.

```
create table AssetClasses(
    ID         int not null auto incrementing primary key,
    Type       char( 1 ) check( Type in( 'A', 'G' )),
    ...,
    constraint UQ_AssetClass_IDType unique( ID, Type )
);
create table Assets(
    ID         int not null primary key,
    ClassType  char( 1 ) check( ClassType = 'A' ),
    ...,
    constraint FK_Assets_AssetClass foreign key( ID, ClassType )
        references AssetClasses( ID, Type )
);
create table AssetGroups(
    ID         int not null primary key,
    ClassType  char( 1 ) check( ClassType = 'G' ),
    ...,
    constraint FK_AssetGroups_AssetClass foreign key( ID, ClassType )
        references AssetClasses( ID, Type )
);
```

There would be a many-to-many intersection table between AssetGroups and Assets allowing an asset to be accessible by many groups and a group to have access to many assets. There would also be an intersection table between Users and AssetClasses so you can share assets (either directly to an Asset or indirectly through an AssetGroup) to users.

This might seem convoluted, and it is a bit, but it gives you everything you asked for. And it is easily extensible -- I soon realized that owner of an asset would have to part of the asset data. As the owner would apply to both an asset and to an asset group, it would go into the AssetClasses table:

```
    OwnerID    int not null,
    constraint FK_AssetClass_Owner foreign key( OwnerID )
        references Users( ID )
```

Any attribute that applied only to an Asset or only to an Asset Group would go in the appropriate subtable.

Comment: Correct me if i am mistaken. I think your Approach is more "One" or "Some" oriented. I would like a "Some" or "All" oriented approach . 
For example how would a user share "All" of of this assets with another user, without having to insert entries for each asset on the intersection table?

Comment: A user shares all assets by creating an entry in the intersection table that gives a specific group access to each asset. So yes, one entry for each asset. If you consider that the difficult part, then take heart in the fact that it only has to be done once. Once the "all" group has been thus defined, sharing all assets is a simple matter of sharing that one group with the other user. Think of this as the Golden Rule of Engineering (Software, Electrical, Mechanical, whatever): the more simple the user interaction, the more complex the design.

Comment: Having said that, it is certainly possible to design a special group entry that means "all assets owned by this user." This would be simpler for the special case of "all assets" and would have the added benefit of including new assets the user may acquire in the future. But test it thoroughly. I can almost guarantee that this one simplifying feature ends up just shifting the complexity to other areas -- specifically, the code required to handle it. But maybe the overall complexity will be less. Test, test, test.

Comment: Yes i was more looking of an approach similar to your second comment.  The key is to avoid adding any newly created asset to the "All" group. Also querying will be done directly on the "Asset" table via the "OwnerId" (Group->Gives access to all assets where "OwnerId" = value)

So avoiding the intersection table i also think would speed up the query.

Comment: Just a general point of modeling advice. Don't make an effort to "speed up the query" -- and certainly don't be making changes to your model -- until you have determined that the performance of the query is adversely impacting the application. Database design has one overall concern: data integrity. Performance can be worked on later -- if it ever becomes an issue. Providing your users erroneous answers but providing them very, very quickly is not a good feature. Simplicity is generally the best for data integrity *and* performance.